# Certbot: "Some challenges failed" when trying to create certificate for wildcard for app on Google Cloud Platform's App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, certbot, google-cloud-dns

*example.com is just as an example. I do own the domain I am trying to work with.*

**What am I trying to do?**

I want to generate an SSL wildcard certificate using certbot to use on Google Cloud Platform, so that urls like *https://this.example.com* work.

**What have I done?**

I have an app engine instance running that uses a custom domain name (*example.com*).
I have a DNS zone in Cloud DNS with *example.com* as DNS name. A/AAAA records pointing to the same IPv4 & IPv6 addresses as are specified in the custom domain tab of App Engine.

**What works?**

Navigating to *https://example.com* or *https://www.example.com* works. Navigating to *http://example.com* or *http://www.example.com* redirects to https.

**What doesn't work?**

This is the command I ran:

```
sudo certbot certonly --dns-google --dns-google-credentials *CREDENTIALS* -d *.example.com
```

With CREDENTIALS being the location of my service account key file.

After a few minutes, I get an error:

```
Domain: example.com
Type: unauthorized
Detail: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.example.com

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address.
```

**What do I think it could be?**

I am hoping it just takes a while to update, but I am not sure.

**EDIT:
The logs. It went through an automatic secret remover tool before I shared it here. Let me know if it removed something that you need to see!

**EDIT2: Added new logs & IAM role(s) for SA

The Service Account I am using has DNS Administrator as role.

```
FILE_LOCATION = Location of credentials file
***** = Hidden

2021-11-25 21:18:03,991:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.40.0
2021-11-25 21:18:03,992:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['--dns-google', '--dns-google-credentials', 'FILE_LOCATION', '-d', '*.example.com', '--dns-google-propagation-seconds', '120']
2021-11-25 21:18:03,992:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#dns-google,PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,PluginEntryPoint#webroot)
2021-11-25 21:18:04,003:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 20
2021-11-25 21:18:04,003:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2021-11-25 21:18:04,004:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator dns-google and installer None
2021-11-25 21:18:04,004:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Single candidate plugin: * dns-google
Description: Obtain certificates using a DNS TXT record (if you are using Google Cloud DNS for DNS).
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IPlugin
Entry point: dns-google = certbot_dns_google.dns_google:Authenticator
Initialized: <certbot_dns_google.dns_google.Authenticator object at 0x7ff1c3afc7c0>
Prep: True
2021-11-25 21:18:04,004:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Selected authenticator <certbot_dns_google.dns_google.Authenticator object at 0x7ff1c3afc7c0> and installer None
2021-11-25 21:18:04,004:INFO:certbot.plugins.selection:Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-google, Installer None
2021-11-25 21:18:04,008:DEBUG:certbot.main:Picked account: <Account(RegistrationResource(body=Registration(key=None, contact=(), agreement=None, status=None, terms_of_service_agreed=None, only_return_existing=None, external_account_binding=None), uri='https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/*****', new_authzr_uri=None, terms_of_service=None), *****, Meta(creation_dt=datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 24, 22, 26, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>), creation_host='*****'))>
2021-11-25 21:18:04,008:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending GET request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory.
2021-11-25 21:18:04,010:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443
2021-11-25 21:18:04,489:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "GET /directory HTTP/1.1" 200 658
2021-11-25 21:18:04,491:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 20:18:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 658
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
  "HgGq9-KQs_w": "https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/adding-random-entries-to-the-directory/33417",
  "keyChange": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/key-change",
  "meta": {
    "caaIdentities": [
      "letsencrypt.org"
    ],
    "termsOfService": "https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf",
    "website": "https://letsencrypt.org"
  },
  "newAccount": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-acct",
  "newNonce": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-nonce",
  "newOrder": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order",
  "revokeCert": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/revoke-cert"
}
2021-11-25 21:18:04,493:INFO:certbot.main:Obtaining a new certificate
2021-11-25 21:18:04,525:DEBUG:certbot.crypto_util:Generating key (2048 bits): /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0036_key-certbot.pem
2021-11-25 21:18:04,529:DEBUG:certbot.crypto_util:Creating CSR: /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0036_csr-certbot.pem
2021-11-25 21:18:04,530:DEBUG:acme.client:Requesting fresh nonce
2021-11-25 21:18:04,530:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending HEAD request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-nonce.
2021-11-25 21:18:04,747:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "HEAD /acme/new-nonce HTTP/1.1" 200 0
2021-11-25 21:18:04,749:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 20:18:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory>;rel="index"
Replay-Nonce: *****
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800


2021-11-25 21:18:04,749:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: *****
2021-11-25 21:18:04,750:DEBUG:acme.client:JWS payload:
b'{\n  "identifiers": [\n    {\n      "type": "dns",\n      "value": "*.example.com"\n    }\n  ]\n}'
2021-11-25 21:18:04,757:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending POST request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order:
{
  "protected": "*****",
  "signature": "*****",
  "payload": "*****"
}
2021-11-25 21:18:05,475:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "POST /acme/new-order HTTP/1.1" 201 338
2021-11-25 21:18:05,476:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 201
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 20:18:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 338
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: *****
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory>;rel="index"
Location: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/*****/*****
Replay-Nonce: *****
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2021-12-02T20:18:05Z",
  "identifiers": [
    {
      "type": "dns",
      "value": "*.example.com"
    }
  ],
  "authorizations": [
    "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/*****"
  ],
  "finalize": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/*****/*****"
}
2021-11-25 21:18:05,477:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: *****
2021-11-25 21:18:05,478:DEBUG:acme.client:JWS payload:
b''
2021-11-25 21:18:05,484:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending POST request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/*****:
{
  "protected": "*****",
  "signature": "*****",
  "payload": ""
}
2021-11-25 21:18:06,101:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "POST /acme/authz-v3/***** HTTP/1.1" 200 386
2021-11-25 21:18:06,103:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 20:18:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 386
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: *****
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory>;rel="index"
Replay-Nonce: *****
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "example.com"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2021-12-02T20:18:05Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/*****/*****",
      "token": "*****"
    }
  ],
  "wildcard": true
}
2021-11-25 21:18:06,103:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: *****
2021-11-25 21:18:06,104:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Performing the following challenges:
2021-11-25 21:18:06,105:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:dns-01 challenge for example.com
2021-11-25 21:18:06,106:WARNING:certbot.plugins.dns_common:Unsafe permissions on credentials configuration file: FILE_LOCATION
2021-11-25 21:18:06,110:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dns/v1/rest
2021-11-25 21:18:06,400:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones?dnsName=example.com.&alt=json
2021-11-25 21:18:06,401:INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
2021-11-25 21:18:06,403:INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
2021-11-25 21:18:06,796:DEBUG:certbot_dns_google.dns_google:Found id of ***** for example.com using name example.com
2021-11-25 21:18:06,800:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones/*****/rrsets?alt=json
2021-11-25 21:18:06,998:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: POST https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones/*****/changes?alt=json
2021-11-25 21:18:07,676:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones/*****/changes/46?alt=json
2021-11-25 21:18:07,894:INFO:certbot.plugins.dns_common:Waiting 120 seconds for DNS changes to propagate
2021-11-25 21:20:07,995:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Waiting for verification...
2021-11-25 21:20:07,996:DEBUG:acme.client:JWS payload:
b'{\n  "resource": "challenge",\n  "type": "dns-01"\n}'
2021-11-25 21:20:08,008:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending POST request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/*****/*****:
{
  "protected": "*****",
  "signature": "*****",
  "payload": "*****"
}
2021-11-25 21:20:08,782:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "POST /acme/chall-v3/*****/***** HTTP/1.1" 200 185
2021-11-25 21:20:08,784:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 20:20:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: *****
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory>;rel="index", <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/*****>;rel="up"
Location: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/*****/*****
Replay-Nonce: *****
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
  "type": "dns-01",
  "status": "pending",
  "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/*****/*****",
  "token": "*****"
}
2021-11-25 21:20:08,784:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: *****
2021-11-25 21:20:09,786:DEBUG:acme.client:JWS payload:
b''
2021-11-25 21:20:09,793:DEBUG:acme.client:Sending POST request to https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/*****:
{
  "protected": "*****",
  "signature": "*****",
  "payload": ""
}
2021-11-25 21:20:11,326:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:443 "POST /acme/authz-v3/***** HTTP/1.1" 200 668
2021-11-25 21:20:11,327:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 20:20:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 668
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: *****
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory>;rel="index"
Replay-Nonce: *****
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "example.com"
  },
  "status": "invalid",
  "expires": "2021-12-02T20:18:05Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "invalid",
      "error": {
        "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns",
        "detail": "DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain",
        "status": 400
      },
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/*****/*****",
      "token": "*****",
      "validated": "2021-11-25T20:20:08Z"
    }
  ],
  "wildcard": true
}
2021-11-25 21:20:11,328:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: *****
2021-11-25 21:20:11,329:WARNING:certbot.auth_handler:Challenge failed for domain example.com
2021-11-25 21:20:11,330:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:dns-01 challenge for example.com
2021-11-25 21:20:11,330:DEBUG:certbot.reporter:Reporting to user: The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: example.com
Type:   dns
Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
2021-11-25 21:20:11,331:DEBUG:certbot.error_handler:Encountered exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 91, in handle_authorizations
    self._poll_authorizations(authzrs, max_retries, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 180, in _poll_authorizations
    raise errors.AuthorizationError('Some challenges have failed.')
certbot.errors.AuthorizationError: Some challenges have failed.

2021-11-25 21:20:11,331:DEBUG:certbot.error_handler:Calling registered functions
2021-11-25 21:20:11,331:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Cleaning up challenges
2021-11-25 21:20:11,334:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dns/v1/rest
2021-11-25 21:20:12,254:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones?dnsName=example.com.&alt=json
2021-11-25 21:20:12,254:INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
2021-11-25 21:20:12,256:INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
2021-11-25 21:20:12,832:DEBUG:certbot_dns_google.dns_google:Found id of ***** for example.com using name example.com
2021-11-25 21:20:12,836:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: GET https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones/*****/rrsets?alt=json
2021-11-25 21:20:13,009:INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: POST https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/*****/managedZones/*****/changes?alt=json
2021-11-25 21:20:13,628:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1382, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1265, in certonly
    lineage = _get_and_save_cert(le_client, config, domains, certname, lineage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 121, in _get_and_save_cert
    lineage = le_client.obtain_and_enroll_certificate(domains, certname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 417, in obtain_and_enroll_certificate
    cert, chain, key, _ = self.obtain_certificate(domains)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 348, in obtain_certificate
    orderr = self._get_order_and_authorizations(csr.data, self.config.allow_subset_of_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 396, in _get_order_and_authorizations
    authzr = self.auth_handler.handle_authorizations(orderr, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 91, in handle_authorizations
    self._poll_authorizations(authzrs, max_retries, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 180, in _poll_authorizations
    raise errors.AuthorizationError('Some challenges have failed.')
certbot.errors.AuthorizationError: Some challenges have failed.
```

Comment: 1) I recommend setting **--dns-google-propagation-seconds** to 120 seconds and trying again. 2)Turn on certbot debugging and/or check the certbot logs dir (--log-dir). Most likely there will be an issue with creating the TXT record in your DNS server for the domain.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks for the comment! It does say this: Unable to determine managed zone for example.com using zone names ['example.com', 'com']. When running "gcloud dns managed-zones list" I can however see NAME: example-com DNS_NAME: example.com VISIBILITY: public.

Comment: Are you using credentials from the same Google Cloud project as the DNS server? Is your DNS server the authoritative name server at your Registrar? Post the relevant section of the certbot logs that interfaces with Google Cloud. Include the real domain name in your question.

Comment: Your problem is that you already have the CNAME **_acme-challenge**. Delete that resource record. Why did you create that record?

Comment: Certbot creates a TXT record. You already have a CNAME. Delete the CNAME.

Comment: @JohnHanley You're right! I'm sorry! I've deleted the CNAME (I don't really know why it was there). This is the new error: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Comment: Edit your question and replace the log file with a new one. NXDOMAIN means that the zone resource record does not exist. Also list the IAM roles assigned to the service account used in your command. Make sure the service account has permission to manage DNS.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for helping me! I've replaced the logs and verified that the Service Account I am using indeed has DNS Administrator as a role

Comment: 1) Set **--dns-google-propagation-seconds** to something like 10 minutes (600). Then start certbot again. Then while certbot is running check if the resource record is created. 2) Show the exact command that you are using in your question. 3) As a debugging test, try a non-wildcard domain name such as test.deskswapp.com

Comment: My earlier comment **Is your DNS server the authoritative name server at your Registrar?**. Google Domains is not supported by certbot. Google Cloud DNS is supported. Which one are you using? Note: You can use Google Domains, it is the NS (name server) records that need to be pointing to a Google Cloud DNS Server. You just cannot use Google Domains DNS servers with certbot (manually you can).

Comment: @JohnHanley I want to thank you very much! The problem was indeed with me using Domains DNS. It created the certificate! It doesn't want to point to my instance on App Engine now, but that is something I think I can figure out on my own. Thank you very much! I've learned a lot already! Have a great day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long comment thread, we figured out the problem.

The OP is using Google Domains for the [Authoritative Name Servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server#Authoritative_name_server).

Certbot does not have a [plugin](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#dns-plugins) for Google Domains DNS servers. Google Domains does not publish an API.

The solution is to manually create the required DNS resource records or [switch to another supported DNS server](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) such as [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns).